# Find any value from boundary value problem

Tags: nonlinear-system, boundary-value-problem

After solving a non-linear boundary value problem I have used a linear approach between known approximates to find the value for any given parameter. I'm having a hard time finding out if this is the normal way to do it and what the error is for this and/or what the alternatives are. It feels quite complicated to find out the error since the process involves both discretization, multi variable newton-raphson iterations and then on top of it a linear approximation.

Thanks!